# How to translate the English structure "To... is to..." as in "To love another person is to see the face of God"?

Tags: traducción, locuciones

In English with have this stucture (En inglés tenemos esta estructura gramatical):

> To... is to...

For example (Por ejemplo):

> To love another person is to see the face of God. - Victor Hugo

How does this structure made in Spanish? (¿Cómo se construye esta estructura en español?)

In particular I want to say in an essay (En particular, quiero decir para un ensayo):

> To not actively prohibit alcohol is to allow drunk driving.

*Ok, this was originally in French (Bueno, esto viene originalmente del francés):

> Pour aimer une autre personne, c'est de voir le visage de Dieu.

Comment: Google Translate (https://translate.google.com) da, para los ejemplos planteados: "**Amar a otra persona es ver la cara de Dios**" y "**No prohibir activamente el alcohol es permitir conducir ebrio.**" un resultado muy parecido al que propone fedorqui en su respuesta y con un esfuerzo mínimo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the structure

> To... is to...

After all you are using the form `<infinitive> + is + <infinitive>` and we have the same structure in Spanish: `<infinitive> + es + <infinitive>`. As so, the sentence:

> To love another person is to see the face of God. - Victor Hugo

Would be translated into Spanish as:

> *Amar* a otra persona *es ver* la cara de Dios.

I googled a little and found out that people tend to translate the sentence using "rostro" instead of "cara" (it sounds more poetic), so better say:

> Amar a otra persona es ver el rostro de Dios.

Following on this, to say:

> To not actively prohibit alcohol is to allow drunk driving.

You can directly say:

> No prohibir el [consumo de] alcohol es permitir que se conduzca borracho.

The last part can have different options:

- *es permitir que se conduzca borracho*.
- *es permitir conducir borracho* - I don't like using two infinitives together.
- *es permitir que haya conductores borrachos* - it says "it allows having drunk drivers".